# Accessing Map attribute with dynamic key in Struts 2 OGNL

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have a list of Strings that are attribute names and a Map.
I'm trying to access a model(ex.project) in the map using attribute name in string list.

Here is what I have now.

```
<s:iterator value="theMap" var="element">
  <tr>
    <s:iterator value="attributeList" var="attrName">
      <td><p><s:property value="#element.Project.#attrName" /></p></td>
    </s:iterator>
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

If I hard code the attribute name it works fine:

```
<td><p><s:property value="#element.Project.projectName" /></p></td>
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I have no utter idea about Struts2/OGNL, but in standard JSP EL it is possible by brace notation like `${element.project[attrName]}`.

Comment: Well. That also did the trick for me. Thanks

Comment: This answer has proven to be useful already. Great Stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Using OGNL `<s:property value="#element.Project[#attrName]" />`